# List of keyEquivalent strings for special keys

Tags: c#, macos, mono, keyboard-shortcuts, monomac

I'm trying to programmatically set the KeyEquivalent and KeyEquivalentModifierMask for my NSMenuItem objects (in MonoMac). For alphanumeric keys ("a-z", "0-9") this is not a problem, but I do want to be able to set key equivalents for keys such as F1-F12 and also the arrow keys, return key, etc.

Is there a list of these keys available somewhere? This is the code I'm using currently for each key (found via Googling)

```
Enter/Return => @\"r"
Escape => @"\E"
Left Arrow => string.Format("%c", 0xF702)
Up Arrow => string.Format("%c", 0xF700)
Right Arrow => string.Format("%c", 0xF703)
Down Arrow => string.Format("%c", 0xF701)
Delete => string.Format("%c", 0x08)
F1 => ?
F2 => ?
...
F12 => ?
```

I haven't tested all of these out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are defined in the [NSKey enum](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSKey/%2a).

---

If you want the values themselves they are in `NSEvent.h` in the Mac OS X  SDK (See [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). The [GnuStep version](http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/libs/gui/trunk/Headers/AppKit/NSEvent.h) of this file could be found on Gna and should include the same constants, it's easy to convert them to C# :

```
enum {
  NSUpArrowFunctionKey = 0xF700,
  NSDownArrowFunctionKey = 0xF701,
  NSLeftArrowFunctionKey = 0xF702,
  NSRightArrowFunctionKey = 0xF703,
  NSF1FunctionKey  = 0xF704,
  NSF2FunctionKey  = 0xF705,
  NSF3FunctionKey  = 0xF706,
  NSF4FunctionKey  = 0xF707,
  NSF5FunctionKey  = 0xF708,
  NSF6FunctionKey  = 0xF709,
  NSF7FunctionKey  = 0xF70A,
  NSF8FunctionKey  = 0xF70B,
  NSF9FunctionKey  = 0xF70C,
  NSF10FunctionKey = 0xF70D,
  NSF11FunctionKey = 0xF70E,
  NSF12FunctionKey = 0xF70F,
  NSF13FunctionKey = 0xF710,
  NSF14FunctionKey = 0xF711,
  NSF15FunctionKey = 0xF712,
  NSF16FunctionKey = 0xF713,
  NSF17FunctionKey = 0xF714,
  NSF18FunctionKey = 0xF715,
  NSF19FunctionKey = 0xF716,
  NSF20FunctionKey = 0xF717,
  NSF21FunctionKey = 0xF718,
  NSF22FunctionKey = 0xF719,
  NSF23FunctionKey = 0xF71A,
  NSF24FunctionKey = 0xF71B,
  NSF25FunctionKey = 0xF71C,
  NSF26FunctionKey = 0xF71D,
  NSF27FunctionKey = 0xF71E,
  NSF28FunctionKey = 0xF71F,
  NSF29FunctionKey = 0xF720,
  NSF30FunctionKey = 0xF721,
  NSF31FunctionKey = 0xF722,
  NSF32FunctionKey = 0xF723,
  NSF33FunctionKey = 0xF724,
  NSF34FunctionKey = 0xF725,
  NSF35FunctionKey = 0xF726,
  NSInsertFunctionKey = 0xF727,
  NSDeleteFunctionKey = 0xF728,
  NSHomeFunctionKey = 0xF729,
  NSBeginFunctionKey = 0xF72A,
  NSEndFunctionKey = 0xF72B,
  NSPageUpFunctionKey = 0xF72C,
  NSPageDownFunctionKey = 0xF72D,
  NSPrintScreenFunctionKey = 0xF72E,
  NSScrollLockFunctionKey = 0xF72F,
  NSPauseFunctionKey = 0xF730,
  NSSysReqFunctionKey = 0xF731,
  NSBreakFunctionKey = 0xF732,
  NSResetFunctionKey = 0xF733,
  NSStopFunctionKey = 0xF734,
  NSMenuFunctionKey = 0xF735,
  NSUserFunctionKey = 0xF736,
  NSSystemFunctionKey = 0xF737,
  NSPrintFunctionKey = 0xF738,
  NSClearLineFunctionKey = 0xF739,
  NSClearDisplayFunctionKey = 0xF73A,
  NSInsertLineFunctionKey = 0xF73B,
  NSDeleteLineFunctionKey = 0xF73C,
  NSInsertCharFunctionKey = 0xF73D,
  NSDeleteCharFunctionKey = 0xF73E,
  NSPrevFunctionKey = 0xF73F,
  NSNextFunctionKey = 0xF740,
  NSSelectFunctionKey = 0xF741,
  NSExecuteFunctionKey = 0xF742,
  NSUndoFunctionKey = 0xF743,
  NSRedoFunctionKey = 0xF744,
  NSFindFunctionKey = 0xF745,
  NSHelpFunctionKey = 0xF746,
  NSModeSwitchFunctionKey = 0xF747
};
```

Comment: They're in [NSKey](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSKey%2f%2a)

Comment: @mhutch Thanks, but you should answer, your answer is a lot better than mine.